# What's the most efficient way of getting the directory from file path without file name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, path, filepath

I want to get the directory from the file path without the file name in JavaScript. I want the inputs and outputs in the following behavior.

```
Input: '/some/path/to/file.txt'
Output: '/some/path/to'

Input: '/some/path/to/file'
Output: '/some/path/to/file'

Input: '/some/folder.with/dot/path/to/file.txt'
Output: '/some/folder.with/dot/path/to'

Input: '/some/file.txt/path/to/file.txt'
Output: '/some/file.txt/path/to'
```

I was thinking of doing this using `RegExp`. But, not sure how the exact RegExp should be written.

Can someone help me with an EFFICIENT solution other than that or the RegExp?

Comment: That is an opinionated question. Better to show the solutions you have in mind and then ask others to chose an efficient one.

Comment: Try: `str = str.replace(/\w+\.\w+$/, "");`

Comment: @anubhava It works perfectly!! :) Thank you so much :) If you can post it as an answer, I can mark it as the correct answer... :)

Comment: @anubhava OP doesn't want the last `/`. So it should be `/\/\w+\.\w+$/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your examples looks like you want to treat anything except last filename as directory name where filename always contains a dot.

To get that part, you can use this code in Javascript:

```
str = str.replace(/\/\w+\.\w+$/, "");
```

Regex `\/\w+\.\w+$` matches a `/` and 1+ word characters followed by a dot followed by another 1+ word characters before end of string. Replacement is just an empty string.

However, do keep in mind that some filenames may not contain any dot character and this replacement won't work in those cases.

Comment: Works really perfectly!!! :) Thank you very much for the valuable answer and the really valuable explanation. :) Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to get the index and then use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to get the desired result.

```js
const strArr = [
  "/some/path/to/file.txt",
  "/some/path/to/file",
  "/some/folder.with/dot/path/to/file.txt",
  "/some/file.txt/path/to/file.txt",
];

const result = strArr.map((s) => {
  if (s.match(/.txt$/)) {
    const index = s.lastIndexOf("/");
    return s.slice(0, index !== -1 ? index : s.length);
  } else return s;
});
console.log(result);
```

Using regex

```js
const strArr = [
  "/some/path/to/file.txt",
  "/some/path/to/file",
  "/some/folder.with/dot/path/to/file.txt",
  "/some/file.txt/path/to/file.txt",
];

const result = strArr.map((s) => s.replace(/\/\w+\.\w+$/, ""));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, @decpk for your answer and suggestions on the correct answer :) Really appreciate :)